# Passing which member to lookup dynamically

Tags: c++, python, dynamic, language-agnostic, macros

I want to determine which attribute to look-up dynamicaly,
Consider below python code:

```
def f(x, a):
    return x.a

class X:
    b = 4

x = X()
print(f(x, b))
```

If python had this property, above code should print 4.

Is there way to do it in any language?
I cannot conceive a way with C++ templates or dynamic typing.

Comment: how would you do this in any language, that doesn't support types with attributes?

Comment: Well, you could write a Lisp interpreter in C++. Are you [Greenspunning](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LevelsOfGreenspunning)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can dynamically access attributes of objects in the way you are attempting.  the built-in function `getattr` will allow you to do this.  As marcin suggested you can just replace f with `getattr`

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr

```
def f(x, a)
  return getattr(x, a)
```

or

```
class X:
    b = 4

getattr(x, a)

print(getattr(x, "b"))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I see that you can do it with python built-in functions or with C# reflection. What I am wondering: Is there a way to do it directly (without using any library  function) ?

Comment: @VolkanSirin I get the impression you want to read more about Python's `__dict__` attributes. Probably [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, use a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

```
def f(x,a):
   return x[a]

x = {}
x[b] = 4
print f(x,b)
```

Comment: I want to be able to use f function with any class, including the ones that i cannot change (to a dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

`f = getattr`

That will make your example work. I think you need to read the python docs: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html